# spaCy Matcher Rule not finding phrase in text

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp, spacy

[image: 1]

Please I have this spaCy matcher object I created with the rule to match an adjective and one or two nouns. Unfortunately, the expected output of **beautiful design**, **smart search**, ***automatic labels**, **optional voice responses** are not being returned. And I can't decipher what the problem is with my code.

```
doc = nlp("Features of the app include a beautiful design, smart search, automatic labels and optional voice responses.")

# Write a pattern for adjective plus one or two nouns
pattern = [{'POS': 'ADJ'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'NOUN', 'OP': '?'}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher and apply the matcher to the doc
matcher.add('ADJ_NOUN_PATTERN', [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)
print('Total matches found:', len(matches))

# Iterate over the matches and print the span text
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print('Match found:', doc[start:end].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. I used the large pipeline, 'en_core_web_lg'.
Which pipeline do you use ? And how do you declare your matcher ?

Here is my code :

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# +Your code

doc = nlp("Features of the app include a beautiful design, smart search, automatic labels and optional voice responses.")

# Write a pattern for adjective plus one or two nouns
pattern = [{'POS': 'ADJ'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}, {'POS': 'NOUN', 'OP': '?'}]

# Add the pattern to the matcher and apply the matcher to the doc
matcher.add('ADJ_NOUN_PATTERN', [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)
print('Total matches found:', len(matches))

# Iterate over the matches and print the span text
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print('Match found:', doc[start:end].text)
```